# how to use jQuery ajax with asp.net user controls?

Tags: asp.net, ajax, jquery

I want to use ajax with asp.net user control,

```
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "*TCSection.ascx/InsertTCSection",
        data: "{id:'" + id + "'}",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (msg) {
            var URL = msg.d;
            alert(URL);
        });
```

.cs code

```
[WebMethod]
public static string InsertTCSection(string id)
{
    string result = "deneme";
    return result; 
}
```

Comment: Are you getting some error?

Comment: i am  adding breakpoint at server side  function and it is not hit

Comment: you cannot call a method kept inside UserControl through jquery, as at runtime there is no such resource as .ascx, it is merged with the page onto which it is kept

Answer (score 5):

**You cannot** call a method kept inside a usercontrol through jquery.
because .ascx controls don't represent real url.

They are meant to be embedded in some ASP.NET page, hence they don't exist at runtime.
what you might do is, to create a separate service and place your method there.
like [webservices.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7477404/web-service-in-asp-net)

see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/579024/calling-an-ascx-page-method-using-jquery), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3392345/using-jquery-ajax-to-call-asp-net-function-in-control-code-behind-instead-of-pag) and many others

Answer (score 3):

i am using generic Handler to  solve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
 $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "*TCSection.ascx/InsertTCSection",
        data: JSON2.stringify({ id: id}, //Your 2nd id is passing value but i dont know where its come from
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (msg) {
            var URL = msg.d;
            alert(URL);
             }
         )};
```

and in cs:

```
[WebMethod]
public static string InsertTCSection(string id)
{
    string result="deneme";
    return result; 
}
```

Comment: id parameter not important i want to learn about ajax with .ascx. is any way to do this ?

Answer (score 1):

I think you might be missing this attribute

```
   [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
```

Before you service class as

```
[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
public class TCSection: System.Web.Services.WebService
{

    [WebMethod]
    public static string InsertTCSection(string id)
    {
    }
 }
```

Or there may be one other reason that path of the webservice is not right.